# How change row color with Null items?

Tags: qt

I want to change color of the row with NULL items (I didn't do setData() or setItem()) in QTableWidget. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To have full control over the items, I would just drop in an item, and then set the background color:

Fill the row with `QTableWidgetItem`'s and then you can change the background color.

```
QTableWidgetItem *newItem = new QTableWidgetItem("");
tableWidget->setItem(row, column, newItem);

QColor color( Qt::red );
tableWidget->item( row, column )->setBackgroundColor( color );
```

That is the main way that I have formatted any cells in the past.

### QStyleSheets

In the documentation for QStyleSheets, QTableView and QTableWidget share the same kind of properties:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtableview

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#alternate-background-color-prop

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#item-sub

It should work with the table and rows, even if it isn't full of items.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I shouldn't set items in table cells.How set color style for exact row?

Comment: I made this through setItemDelegateForRow() and made my own class TableDelegate: QStyledItemDelegate where overload paint function.